# Websphere Liberty server.xml featuremanager error

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

In RAD, our Websphere Liberty server.xml shows with a red error whose description is:

*The enabled features require that a keyStore element and a user registry are defined in the server configuration.

 Use the server configuration editor to add these items.*

But, we DO have those things. The passwords are not real pwds.  Also this is not the whole server.xml, just the relevant parts.

server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- This template enables security. To get the full use of all the capabilities, a keystore and user registry are required. -->

<!-- For the keystore, default keys are generated and stored in a keystore. 
     To provide the keystore password, generate an
     encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it below in 
     the password attribute of the keyStore element. 
     Then uncomment the keyStore element. -->

     <sslDefault outboundSSLRef="alternateSSLSettings"/>

     <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"/>

     <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="C:\Temp\ARO\ServerKeyFile.jks" password="{xor}MTArbQg2LDo=" type="JKS"/>

     <keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" location="C:\Temp\ARO\ServerKeyFile.jks" password="{xor}MTArbQg2LDo=" type="JKS"/>

     <ssl id="alternateSSLSettings" keyStoreRef="alternateKeyStore" trustStoreRef="alternateTrustStore"/>

     <keyStore id="alternateKeyStore" location="C:\Temp\ARO\ServerKeyFile.jks" password="{xor}MTArbQg2LDo=" type="JKS"/>

     <keyStore id="alternateTrustStore" location="C:\Temp\ARO\ServerKeyFile.jks" password="{xor}MTArbQg2LDo=" type="JKS"/>


<!--For a user registry configuration, configure your user registry. For 
    example, configure a basic user registry using the
    basicRegistry element. Specify your own user name below in the name 
     attribute of the user element. For the password, 
    generate an encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it 
    in the password attribute of the user element.
    Then uncomment the user element. -->
 <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
    <user name="admin" password="zzzzzz"/>
</basicRegistry>


<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

<library id="DB2JCCLib">
    <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource id="aroDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/aro" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2JCCLib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="DBNAME" password="zzz" portNumber="60000" serverName="1.2.3.4" user="catsapp"/>
</dataSource>


<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

<application id="AROEAR" location="AROEAR.ear" type="ear"/>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Was this imported as a Maven or Gradle project ?

Comment: @ScottKurz - No. Our security team irrationally forbids us from using Maven (don't get me started). It's Websphere Liberty 19 with RAD 9.6.1, and it happens even before I install our j2ee app.

Comment: Have you tried re-validating? Right click on the server.xml in the Project Explorer view and select Validate.

Comment: @Erin - I had deleted the marker, the cleaned an rebuilt each time i tried to change something to satisfy the validator.  I just tried your method and got the same result in that the error is still there.  I should point out that the server actually runs fine if I turn validation off.  So this error isn't hurting the real runtime, but I would like the validator to not have to be turned off if I can.

Comment: I took the small snippet that you included and created a server.xml and could not reproduce the problem nor could I see anything obvious in the code that might be causing this issue. If you have a server.xml with just that snippet in it can you still reproduce the problem? If not are you willing to attach the full server configuration?

Comment: @Erin - Added the full current server.xml with a couple things redacted.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the problem.  I am wondering if this is something that has been fixed.  What version of RAD are you using?

Comment: @Erin - 9.6.1.  Build ID: RADO961-I20170505_1050

Comment: That corresponds the the 17.0.0.1 version of WebSphere Developer Tools.  I pulled it down from here: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-developer-tools-releases/ and still could not reproduce the problem but I would suggest moving up to a newer version to see if that helps since this is well over 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

When I added the below line to the `server.xml`, it eliminated the error for me.

```xml
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="keypassword"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your answer to address this, but in the future: The website will treat XML as though it is HTML. Since browser's don't recognize `<keyStore … />`, it isn't rendered. You can fix this by treating it as code. The easiest way to do that is by indenting the code four spaces. Also, be sure to preview your answer before posting it so that you can catch these types of errors.